# Add Cell values rather than combine cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small problem, probably solved by a simple change. I have some code that is basically interpolating some data at every point. But when i go to paste the interpolated value into the new set of cells, i find that the two cells used have been combined rather than added, i.e Cells(1,1) = 1 & Cells(1,2) = 2 A3 = 12 rather than A3 = 3. Is this a quick fix? Code is below.  `DataColumn` and `newDataColumn` are defined in previous part of the code, and it makes no difference if I sub these for "A" and "B" respectively.

```
        Dim i2 As Long
        i2 = 2
        For i2 = i2 To TotalNumber - 1
        Dim A1 As String
        Dim A2 As String
        Dim A3 As Double
        Dim A4 As Double

        A1 = Cells(i2, DataColumn).Value
        A2 = Cells(i2 + 1, DataColumn).Value
        A3 = A1 + A2
        A4 = A3 / 2
        Cells((i2 * 2), newDataColumn) = A4
        Next i2

        End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you can give me

Mark

Comment: I think this may be down to the line `A3 = A1 + A2` or how ive got the values of A1 and A2

Comment: Is there a reason you've declared A1 & A2 as strings?

Comment: @Absinthe just noticed that and changed them to `Double` code works fine now . Thank you

Comment: Bit cheeky answering your own question using my solution, but your'e welcome :)

Comment: @Absinthe i was in the process of writing the solution when your message came up, i can delete if you would like the credit though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the type of variable for A1 and A2 from "String" to "Double" Code now works as intended
New Code can be seen below

```
    Dim i2 As Long
    i2 = 2
    For i2 = i2 To TotalNumber - 1
    Dim A1 As Double
    Dim A2 As Double
    Dim A3 As Double
    Dim A4 As Double

    A1 = Cells(i2, DataColumn).Value
    A2 = Cells(i2 + 1, DataColumn).Value
    A3 = A1 + A2
    A4 = A3 / 2
    Cells((i2 * 2), newDataColumn) = A4
    Next i2

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

one minor change

```
A3 = CDbl(A1) + CDbl(A2)
```

Comment: What does `CDbl` mean? Does it take the absoulte value or something like  that?

Comment: You have declared A1 and A2 as strings. CDbl converts them to double precision numbers, if they are proper numbers stored as text.

Comment: @MacrinSzaleniec Awsome thank you for explaining what the code meant, means a lot :)